# System Tray - setting image dynamically is unstable

Tags: java, linux, system-tray

Today I tried to change system tray image dynamically as :

```
getTrayIcon().setImage(imageB);
```

But sometimes I have error thrown as :

> Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
> Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)   Serial number of
> failed request:  6724   Current serial number in output stream:  6724
>
> Java Result: 1

or this error :

> The program 'java' received an X Window System error. This probably
> reflects a bug in the program. The error was 'BadMatch (invalid
> parameter attributes)'.   (Details: serial 1139091 error_code 8
> request_code 73 minor_code 0)   (Note to programmers: normally, X
> errors are reported asynchronously;    that is, you will receive the
> error a while after causing it.    To debug your program, run it with
> the --sync command line    option to change this behavior. You can
> then get a meaningful    backtrace from your debugger if you break on
> the gdk_x_error() function.)
>
> Java Result: 1

... I have no idea where that error comes from so I really like to hear your opinion of maybe how to optimize/workaround the code?

- OS linux x64 (XFCE4)
- JRE 1.7.0_72-b14
- JDK 1.7

Thanks

Comment: What window manager are you using? Is `getTrayIcon` a typo? I can't find it in the docs. Is that the complete error message? Do you get a stacktrace too?

Comment: @Patrick Collins The "java.awt.TrayIcon" object; And, yes, this is the complete error text I get in my console output; The desktop environment is xfce4